# Toggle Button Font type remains unchanged

Tags: android

I am facing this strange issue : following is my toggle button :

```
      <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toggle_notify"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_toggle_yes_no"
                style="@style/edit_profile_toggle_style"
                android:checked="false"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center|right"/>
```

and

```
      <style name="edit_profile_toggle_style">
           <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
          <item name="font_type">@string/font_bold</item>
         <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
      </style>
```

now I am able to change the textSize and textColor , but font_type is ArielBold , and it not working only for toggle button. Rest of the app , "font_type" thing is working fine. Please give a good example wherein I can actually customize the toggle btn.

PS : I've tried android:fontStyle="@string/font_bold" and its not working !

Comment: Ariel Bold or Arial Bold ?...check the spelling in your string "font_bold" for your font

Comment: yeah.. my typo...As I said, things are working fine elsewhere in app. just this Toggle thing is taking on my nerves.

Comment: for which other controls it is working for the font - Arial Bold

Comment: Common.. why down vote ??

Comment: i have not downvoted anything here ok and i asked which other controls are working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKAY . Now I finally discussed the thought with my colleague and came to a conclusion that by "customizing toggle button" I can customize my text inside.

Heres a sample of what I did.

```
      public class CustomToggleButton extends ToggleButton { 
        //some code here
```

}
 then in xml ,

```
           <com.mysample.CustomToggleButton 
            android:id="@+id/toggle_notify"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_toggle_yes_no"
            style="@style/edit_profile_toggle_style"
            android:checked="false"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center|right"/>
```

and tada ... it works !!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use "android:textStyle"

```
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
```

also make sure your style extends TextAppearance

```
<style name="edit_profile_toggle_style" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
```

Comment: No, I didn't just want it bold , but also make it Arial. I found the solution and I am sharing it below. Thank you for your time :)