# How apply fontFamily to an android toggle button?

Tags: android, togglebutton, font-family

I created a font family for my app (res/font/montserrat.xml):

```
<font-family
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        android:font="@font/montserrat_medium"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="500"
        app:font="@font/montserrat_medium"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="500"/>
    <font
        android:font="@font/montserrat_mediumitalic"
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="500"
        app:font="@font/montserrat_mediumitalic"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="500"/>
</font-family>
```

Then I included the font family in my app theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat</item>
</style>
```

As result each style for view and buttons inherits the family font from the app theme, except the toggle buttons.

I tried to adding the font family in toggle buttons style and directly in the widget too, but nothing seems to work. 
Does anyone have an idea of why?

Comment: _Possible Duplicate:_ [Toggle Button Font type remains unchanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463368/toggle-button-font-type-remains-unchanged)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle Button Font type remains unchanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463368/toggle-button-font-type-remains-unchanged)